# Using XPATH with Python, do I really need to use get() or getall() or does the xpath string suffice

Tags: python, xpath

Using XPATH with Python, do I really need to use get() or getall() or does the xpath string suffice

For example, is this ok?

`product_links = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"box_product")]/@href')`

or do I really need to use

`product_links = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"box_product")]/@href').getall()`

Or is it so that when using an attribute @attribute works, but to retrieve the data (text) within the html tags itself then we use get() and getall()

question: when do I need to use variant 1 `/@href` or variant 2 `/@href').getall()`?

The goal is to obtain a workable array of links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `response.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"box_product")]/@href')` gives you only an instance of Selector (i.e. a recipe for getting the results you want) instead of the actual results.

To get the actual results, you need to call either `get()`, which will give you only the first match, or `getall()`, which will return all matches.

So for your use case, go with `getall()`.

=====================

Example and read more @ https://www.pythongasm.com/introduction-to-scrapy/

[image]