# Scrapy / Xpath not working to get href-element?

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

i try to scrape something from this site and working in the scrapy shell;
https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g186332-d216481-Reviews-Blackpool_Zoo-Blackpool_Lancashire_England.html

On the site i have the following part of the code and i want to get the href-informations for all of this three a-elements:

```
<div class="fvqxY f dlzPP">
  <div class="Lvkmj"><a class="bfQwA _G B- _S _T c G_ P0 ddFHE cnvzr bTBvn" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"
      href="http://www.blackpoolzoo.org.uk"><span class="WlYyy cacGK Wb">Visit website</span><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        width="16px" height="16px" class="fecdL d Vb wQMPa">
        <path d="M7.561 15.854l-1.415-1.415 8.293-8.293H7.854v-2h10v10h-2V7.561z"></path>
      </svg></a></div>
  <div class="Lvkmj"><a class="bfQwA _G B- _S _T c G_ P0 ddFHE cnvzr bTBvn" rel="nofollow" target="_self"
      href="tel:%2B44%201253%20830830"><span class="WlYyy cacGK Wb">Call</span></a></div>
  <div class="Lvkmj"><a class="bfQwA _G B- _S _T c G_ P0 ddFHE cnvzr bTBvn" rel="nofollow" target="_self"
      href="mailto:info@blackpoolzoo.org.uk"><span class="WlYyy cacGK Wb">Email</span></a></div>
</div>
```

I tried it with this xpath - which works for me fine in the chrome-inspector - but i only get an empty result

```
>>> response.xpath("//div[@class='Lvkmj']//ancestor::a/@href") 
[]
```

I also checked the first div with class = "Lvkmj" and get this result:

```
>>> response.xpath("//div[@class='Lvkmj']").get()                                                                   s="WlYyy cacGK Wb">Visit website</s
'<div class="Lvkmj"><a class="bfQwA _G B- _S _T c G_ P0 ddFHE cnvzr bTBvn" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><span clas 8.293-8.293H7.854v-2h10v10h-2V7.56s="WlYyy cacGK Wb">Visit website</span><svg viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="16px" height="16px" class="fecdL d Vb wQMPa"><path d="M7.561 15.854l-1.415-1.415 8.293-8.293H7.854v-2h10v10h-2V7.561z"></path></svg></a></div>'
>>>
```

There i realized that at the first glance its the whole div-element - but then i saw that it looks exact the same like in the inspecto but for whatever reason the href-element is missing.

Why is the href-element missing when using the scapy shell in that case?

Below you can find the full code -

```
import scrapy

class ZoosSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'zoos'
  allowed_domains = ['www.tripadvisor.co.uk']
  start_urls = [
                "https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attractions-g186216-Activities-c48-a_allAttractions.true-United_Kingdom.html",
                "https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attractions-g186216-Activities-c53-a_allAttractions.true-United_Kingdom.html"
              ]

  def parse(self, response):
    tmpSEC = response.xpath("//section[@data-automation='AppPresentation_SingleFlexCardSection']")
    for elem in tmpSEC:
      link = response.urljoin(elem.xpath(".//a/@href").get())   
      yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parseDetails)             

  def parseDetails(self, response):
    tmpName = response.xpath("//h1[@data-automation='mainH1']/text()").get()  
    tmpLink = response.xpath("//div[@class='Lvkmj']//ancestor::a/@href ").getall()
    tmpErg = response.xpath("//div[@class='dlzPP']//ancestor::div[@class='WlYyy diXIH dDKKM']/text()").getall()
    
    yield {
      "cat": tmpErg[1],
      "link": tmpLink,
      "name": tmpName ,
    }
```

UPDATE - at first the solution from @Fazlul worked great - but after several tries there is no more output for the HREFs-list again - this is part of the log i get from scrapy:

```
2021-11-18 12:16:32 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://localhost:62481 "GET /session/7dacecfe2b35d929244b907b93efd712/url HTTP/1.1" 200 140
2021-11-18 12:16:32 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2021-11-18 12:16:32 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g580423-d3427163-Reviews-Pontefract_Races-Pontefract_West_Yorkshire_England.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attractions-g186216-Activities-c53-a_allAttractions.true-United_Kingdom.html)
2021-11-18 12:16:32 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://localhost:62481/session/7dacecfe2b35d929244b907b93efd712/url {"url": "https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g190792-d3250215-Reviews-Cartmel_Racecourse-Grange_over_Sands_Lake_District_Cumbria_England.html"}
2021-11-18 12:16:34 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://localhost:62481 "POST /session/7dacecfe2b35d929244b907b93efd712/url HTTP/1.1" 200 14
2021-11-18 12:16:34 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2021-11-18 12:16:34 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://localhost:62481/session/7dacecfe2b35d929244b907b93efd712/source {}
2021-11-18 12:16:34 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://localhost:62481 "GET /session/7dacecfe2b35d929244b907b93efd712/source HTTP/1.1" 200 732552
2021-11-18 12:16:34 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2021-11-18 12:16:34 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://localhost:62481/session/7dacecfe2b35d929244b907b93efd712/url {}
[1118/121634.931:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Evidon -- evidon-notice-link not found on page, cant display the consent link.", source: https://c.evidon.com/sitenotice/evidon-sitenotice-tag.js (1)
2021-11-18 12:16:34 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://localhost:62481 "GET /session/7dacecfe2b35d929244b907b93efd712/url HTTP/1.1" 200 156
2021-11-18 12:16:34 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2021-11-18 12:16:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g190792-d3250215-Reviews-Cartmel_Racecourse-Grange_over_Sands_Lake_District_Cumbria_England.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attractions-g186216-Activities-c53-a_allAttractions.true-United_Kingdom.html)
2021-11-18 12:16:34 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://localhost:62481/session/7dacecfe2b35d929244b907b93efd712/url {"url": "https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g186332-d7692268-Reviews-Coral_Island_Blackpool-Blackpool_Lancashire_England.html"}
2021-11-18 12:16:36 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://localhost:62481 "POST /session/7dacecfe2b35d929244b907b93efd712/url HTTP/1.1" 200 14
2021-11-18 12:16:36 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2021-11-18 12:16:36 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://localhost:62481/session/7dacecfe2b35d929244b907b93efd712/source {}
2021-11-18 12:16:36 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://localhost:62481 "GET /session/7dacecfe2b35d929244b907b93efd712/source HTTP/1.1" 200 872845
2021-11-18 12:16:36 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2021-11-18 12:16:36 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://localhost:62481/session/7dacecfe2b35d929244b907b93efd712/url {}
[1118/121636.173:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Evidon -- evidon-notice-link not found on page, cant display the consent link.", source: https://c.evidon.com/sitenotice/evidon-sitenotice-tag.js (1)
2021-11-18 12:16:36 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://localhost:62481 "GET /session/7dacecfe2b35d929244b907b93efd712/url HTTP/1.1" 200 141
2021-11-18 12:16:36 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2021-11-18 12:16:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g186332-d7692268-Reviews-Coral_Island_Blackpool-Blackpool_Lancashire_England.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attractions-g186216-Activities-c53-a_allAttractions.true-United_Kingdom.html)
2021-11-18 12:16:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g656899-d13201486-Reviews-Gala_Bingo-Cramlington_Northumberland_England.html>
{'name': 'Gala Bingo', 'HREFs': []}
2021-11-18 12:16:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g580427-d2663587-Reviews-Romford_Greyhound_Stadium-Romford_Greater_London_England.html>
{'name': 'Romford Greyhound Stadium', 'HREFs': []}
```

Comment: Please share you code.

Comment: Added the full code above - problem in the line:
tmpLink = response.xpath("//div[@class='Lvkmj']//ancestor::a/@href ").getall()

Comment: I see, but I can't see how / where `parseDetails` is called and `response` is passed to it.

Comment: here it is called:
      yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parseDetails)

Comment: I shortened the code above - it is running fine - the only problem is that only cat and name get results - link is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rapid1898 Here is the working solution so far using SeleniumRequest

```
import scrapy

from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest


class ZoosSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'zoos'
    allowed_domains = ['www.tripadvisor.co.uk']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url="https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attractions-g186216-Activities-c53-a_allAttractions.true-United_Kingdom.html",
             wait_time= 3,
             callback=self.parse)
    def parse(self, response):
        tmpSEC = response.xpath( "//section[@data-automation='AppPresentation_SingleFlexCardSection']")
        for elem in tmpSEC:
            link = response.urljoin(elem.xpath(".//a/@href").get())
            yield SeleniumRequest(url=link, callback=self.parseDetails)

    def parseDetails(self, response):
        tmpName = response.xpath("//h1[@data-automation='mainH1']/text()").get()  
        tmpLink = response.xpath("//div[@class='Lvkmj']/a/@href").getall()    
    
        yield {
        "name": tmpName ,
        "HREFs": tmpLink
        }
```

Settings.py file:

```
#Middleware

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
}

#Selenium
from shutil import which
SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('chromedriver')
# '--headless' if using chrome instead of firefox
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS = ['--headless']
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Sandown Park Racecourse', 'HREFs': ['http://www.sandown.co.uk/', 'tel:%2B44%201372%20464348', 'mailto:sandown.ticketing@thejockeyclub.co.uk']}
2021-11-18 00:55:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g656899-d13201486-Reviews-Gala_Bingo-Cramlington_Northumberland_England.html>
{'name': 'Gala Bingo', 'HREFs': ['https://www.galabingoclubs.co.uk/club/cramlington.html', 
'tel:%2B44%201670%20739739', 'mailto:Cramlington.club@galaleisure.com']}
2021-11-18 00:55:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g580427-d2663587-Reviews-Romford_Greyhound_Stadium-Romford_Greater_London_England.html>
{'name': 'Romford Greyhound Stadium', 'HREFs': []}
2021-11-18 00:55:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g190818-d7364032-Reviews-Wetherby_Racecourse-Wetherby_Leeds_West_Yorkshire_England.html>
{'name': 'Wetherby Racecourse', 'HREFs': ['http://www.wetherbyracing.co.uk', 'tel:%2B44%201937%20582035']}
2021-11-18 00:55:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g580423-d3427163-Reviews-Pontefract_Races-Pontefract_West_Yorkshire_England.html>
{'name': 'Pontefract Races', 'HREFs': ['http://www.pontefract-races.co.uk/', 'tel:%2B44%201977%20781307', 'mailto:info@pontefract-races.co.uk']}
2021-11-18 00:55:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g190792-d3250215-Reviews-Cartmel_Racecourse-Grange_over_Sands_Lake_District_Cumbria_England.html>
{'name': 'Cartmel Racecourse', 'HREFs': ['http://www.cartmel-racecourse.co.uk', 'tel:%2B44%2015395%2036340', 'mailto:info@cartmel-racecourse.co.uk']}
2021-11-18 00:55:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g186332-d7692268-Reviews-Coral_Island_Blackpool-Blackpool_Lancashire_England.html>
{'name': 'Coral Island Blackpool', 'HREFs': []}
2021-11-18 00:55:53 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-11-18 00:55:53 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: DELETE http://127.0.0.1:60913/session/8821f802ba0aeaa844dec796ad9187b3 {}
2021-11-18 00:55:53 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://127.0.0.1:60913 "DELETE /session/8821f802ba0aeaa844dec796ad9187b3 HTTP/1.1" 200 14
2021-11-18 00:55:53 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2021-11-18 00:55:56 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/response_bytes': 19882232,
 'downloader/response_count': 31,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 31
```

..so on

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath:

```
//div[@class='Lvkmj']//ancestor::a/@href
```

shows results ...because your second `//` tells the XPath engine:find any descendant node of the current node and then `ancestor::a` tells the engine find any ancestor-element named a. And because the a's do have descendants your XPath gives result....BUT there is a much better way: Just use:

```
//div[@class='Lvkmj']/a/@href
```

`/a` means: just give me the direct `child` named `a` of the `div[@class='Lvkmj']`

But this does not solve your problem.

Your question: *Why is the href-element missing when using the scapy shell in that case?*

Because I think it is using only the source of the document not the updated(by javascript) dom.

And if it would use the updated dom your line

```
tmpLink = response.xpath("//div[@class='Lvkmj']//ancestor::a/@href ").getall()
```

returns an array of strings. So you have to loop threw the results or if you are only interested in the [first result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63859425/3710053) use:

```
tmpLink = response.xpath("//div[@class='Lvkmj']/a/@href ").get()
```

Comment: OK i see - so when i understand it correct there is now way to get this 3 href-elements with scrapy - right?
(cause scrapy isn´t reading the updated (javascript) dom - and thats the reason i don´t have any results)

Comment: And i don´t need the very first element - its ok to get all 3 href-informations - nested in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the answer of @Siebe Jongebloed (no results - cause there seems to happen some javascript dom-changes) i tried scrapy_selenium to get the data -

So i changed the code to this:

```
import scrapy
from shutil import which

from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = r"C:\Users\Polzi\Documents\DEV\Python-Private\chromedriver.exe"
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['--headless', "--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu"]
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
}

class ZoosSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'zoos'
  allowed_domains = ['www.tripadvisor.co.uk']
  start_urls = [
                "https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attractions-g186216-Activities-c53-a_allAttractions.true-United_Kingdom.html"
                ]  
  existList = []  

  def parse(self, response):
    tmpSEC = response.xpath("//section[@data-automation='AppPresentation_SingleFlexCardSection']")
    for elem in tmpSEC:
      link = response.urljoin(elem.xpath(".//a/@href").get())   
      yield SeleniumRequest(url=link, callback=self.parseDetails)  

  def parseDetails(self, response):
    tmpName = response.xpath("//h1[@data-automation='mainH1']/text()").get()  
    tmpLink = response.xpath("//div[@class='Lvkmj']/a/@href").getall()    
    
    yield {
      "name": tmpName ,
      "HREFs": tmpLink
    }
```

But the HREFs-result list is still empty...